# Upload data to firebase through a java class and retrieve one attribute in another activity

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWPWe.png)I am trying to save data to firebase using this code.
Everything works fine. I was saving the data creating new children uder users>uid. but now when i try to save the data by creating an object and passing that object in setvalue, the app crashes. Please help.

```
public class RegComplete extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Name, Surname, Address, Tel, DateOfBirth,Username;
private String _name, _surname, _address, _Tel, _DateOfBirth,_UserName, email;
public String uid = "";

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
private DatabaseReference fdatabase;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser objuser = auth.getCurrentUser();

List<String> lstSports = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> lstSteden = new ArrayList<String>();
String strSport1,strSport2,strSport3;
public String strCity;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg_complete);

    fdatabase = database.getReference();

    fdatabase.child("Steden").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot DS:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String CityName = DS.child("CityName").getValue(String.class);
                City stad = new City(CityName);
                lstSteden.add(stad.CityName);
            }
            final Spinner CitySpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CitySpin);
            ArrayAdapter<String> CityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegComplete.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstSteden);
            CityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            CitySpin.setAdapter(CityAdapter);
            CitySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    strCity = CitySpin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




    fdatabase.child("SPORTS").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String sportName = ds.child("SportName").getValue(String.class);
                Sport objsport = new Sport(sportName);

                lstSports.add(objsport.SportName);
            }

            final Spinner Sports1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SportSpinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> SportAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegComplete.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstSports);
            SportAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Sports1.setAdapter(SportAdapter);
            Sports1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    strSport1 = Sports1.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
            final Spinner Sports2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SportSpinner2);
            Sports2.setAdapter(SportAdapter);
            Sports2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    strSport2 = Sports2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            final Spinner Sports3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SportSpinner3);
            Sports3.setAdapter(SportAdapter);
            Sports3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    strSport3 = Sports3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    Name = findViewById(R.id.NameeditText);
    _name = Name.getText().toString();
    Surname = findViewById(R.id.SurnameEditText);
    _surname = Surname.getText().toString();
    Address = findViewById(R.id.AdressEditText);
    _address = Address.getText().toString();
    Tel = findViewById(R.id.TelEditText);
    _Tel = Tel.getText().toString();
    DateOfBirth = findViewById(R.id.DOBEditText);
    _DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth.getText().toString();
    Username = findViewById(R.id.UserIDEditText);
    _UserName = Username.getText().toString();
    email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();


}
public void btnSave_Click(View V){
    User usinfo = new User(email,_UserName,_name,_surname,_address,strCity,_Tel,_DateOfBirth,strSport1,strSport2,strSport3,uid);

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS");
    uid = objuser.getUid();
    mdatabase.child(uid).setValue(usinfo);

    Intent i = new Intent(RegComplete.this, LoginActivity.class);
    Toast.makeText(RegComplete.this ,"Registration Complete" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

The code for USER.class

```
public class User {

public String Email;
public String UserName;
public String Name;
public String SurName;
public String StreetAdress;
public String City;
public String Tel;
public String DOB;
public String Sport1;
public String Sport2;
public String Sport3;
public String UserId;
public User(){
    // Default constructor required by Firebase
}

public User(String email, String userName, String name, String surName, String streetAdress, String city, String tel, String DOB, String sport1, String sport2, String sport3, String userId) {
    Email = email;
    UserName = userName;
    Name = name;
    SurName = surName;
    StreetAdress = streetAdress;
    City = city;
    Tel = tel;
    this.DOB = DOB;
    Sport1 = sport1;
    Sport2 = sport2;
    Sport3 = sport3;
    UserId = userId;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getSurName() {
    return SurName;
}

public String getStreetAdress() {
    return StreetAdress;
}

public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

public String getTel() {
    return Tel;
}

public String getDOB() {
    return DOB;
}

public String getSport1() {
    return Sport1;
}

public String getSport2() {
    return Sport2;
}

public String getSport3() {
    return Sport3;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return UserId;
}
```

}

And i am also trying to retrieve UserName for the user with which i am signed in  in another activity. 
using this code.

```
   mdatabase.child("USERS").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                userinf = ds.child(uid).getValue(User.class);
            };

            txtUserNaam.setText(userinf.UserName);
        }
```

Where

```
DatabaseReference mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Please help

Comment: What is the error and the stack trace when the app crashes?

Comment: Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: city

Comment: please let us see your database structure

Comment: I cannot add pictures, so theres an embedded link at the start of the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is getting confused between this field:

```
public String City;
```

And this getter:

```
public String getCity() {
    return City;
}
```

The field defines a property `City`, while the getter defines a property `city`. As you can see the case is different between the two, which leads to the error message.

The easiest fix is to mark all your fields as private:

```
private String City;
```

This keeps Firebase from considering them while reading/writing users.

Comment: This solved the error but now it only saves the UserName in the database as an empty property and nothing else shows up in the database either

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the help with the first problem.

Comment: The second problem is that i want to get only the username property from this specific user. 
The database structure is as follows 
Root > USERS>"the userID">properties 
I only want a specific property from a specific user